# Girl is drugged and on the run with the protagonist

Tags: identify-this-movie, action, thriller

The protagonist is a secret agent / spy and meets the girl somewhere. The hero is chased by gangs everywhere he lands up and the girl is also targeted by virtue of being with him. Girl goes hysterical at being chased and shot at and protagonist pumps a bunch of drugs into her to make her calm down... and then goes on the run with her. A good part of the movie is depicted in glimpses of different places (new one each time) that the girl sees, whenever she's coming round and then gets pumped with more drugs.

Eventually, tables turn and she ends up saving the protagonist and while whisking him away gives him a dose of the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like [Knight and Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1013743/combined) from 2010 with Tom Cruise and Cameron Diaz. From IMDb:

> June Havens finds her everyday life tangled with that of [Roy Miller], a secret agent who has realized he isn't supposed to survive his latest mission. As their campaign to stay alive stretches across the globe, they soon learn that all they can count on is each other.

Roy keeps drugging June to keep her safe, but in the end, she does that to *him*, disguised as a nurse. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Perfect. That's the one. Thank you very much Walt. It was gnawing my brains off :D